# two sum problem always returns empty array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

It always returns empty array.

Implement solution to two sum problem in javascript

```js
function twoSum(nums, target) {
  const map = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    let comp = target - nums[i];
    if (map[comp] !== undefined) {
      return [map[comp], i];
    } else {
      map[comp] = i;
    }
  }
  return [];
}

console.log(twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function logic is correct but there seems to be a small mistake. Instead of storing the complement of the number (comp) in the map, you should store the actual number in the map.

Here's the corrected solution:

```js
function twoSum(nums, target) {
  const map = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    let comp = target - nums[i];
    if (map[comp] !== undefined) {
      return [map[comp], i];
    } else {
      map[nums[i]] = i;  // Store the actual number, not its complement.
    }
  }
  return [];
}

console.log(twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9));  // Should return [0, 1]
```

Comment: @mplungjan no I didn't use chatgpt  I'm just trying to help

Comment: Ok, I will give you the benefit of doubt. But the other answer I flagged was 100% sure chatGPT

Comment: Converting a long to bytes for efficient transmission  I solved this problem myself, but I also wondered about the solution of chatgpt, it made more sense and I liked it very much, so I shared it.  @mplungjan

Comment: 1. It is banned. 2. You did not change anything or give credit so plagiarism.

Comment: I genuinely appreciate your concern. I wasn’t aware of the specific rules surrounding the use of ChatGPT’s solutions on this platform. My intention was to share a solution that I found efficient and insightful, and in no way to take undue credit.

In the future, I'll ensure to give proper attribution where necessary and familiarize myself better with the guidelines to prevent such oversights. I apologize for any confusion and will take steps to rectify the situation.

Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look below:

1. Store each number and its index in the map, not the complement
2. Check if the complement exists in the map, not the number itself
3. Return the indices, not the numbers

```
function twoSum(nums, target) {
    const numsMap = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        const num = nums[i];
        const complement = target - num;
        if(numsMap[complement] !== undefined) {
            return [numsMap[complement], i];
        }
        numsMap[num] = i;
    }
}
const nums = [2,7,11,15];
const target = 9;

const indices = twoSum(nums, target);
console.log(indices); // [0,1]
```